# Add basemaps in QGIS - what differs Tile Services from QuickMapServices QMS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

- Environment
  QGIS-version: 3.14.0-Pi
  QuickMapServices Plugin: 0.19.11.1

I want to use background maps inside QGIS (QGIS version 3.14.0-Pi) and can do that by using f.e.:

1. WebMapTileService (can be done inside QGIS as defined XYZ Tile Services)
2. QuickMapServices (are integrated inside the QMS Plugin)

Often as I tried to use QMS integration the first thing I see is a watermark or the hint to an expired API key. Sure I can use the catalog search and find many entries, but it looks like the catalog data are coming from nextgis.com (and they are expecting a key which isn't possible for me to enter somewhere inside QMS).
Whereas as I'm using the WebMapTileService nothing similar has happened - and I'm also able to pass a key into the request.

So I'm a bit confused and don't understand:
What is technically the difference in between QMS versus WebapTileService?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. AS a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your question to eliminate the numbered list of questions.

Comment: Thx for the hint @Vince: You're right. I just keep track of it and modified my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the data provider URL for WMTS, while QMS conveniently collects these URLs for you.

Technically speaking, QMS loads (most?) layers as WMS/WMTS

Comment: To expand this a little: The WMTS service is a standard specified by the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) to provide map data and is not something exclusively used by QGIS.

Comment: Does that mean QMS and WMTS are both loading WMS/WMTS data and nearly the significant difference is: QMS provides a ready configured endpoint and WMTS is expecting me to configure it? That would explain why I didn't found the possibility to define a token inside QMS in the regular frontend...

Comment: @squeezer44 yes, that's pretty much it